# How to search an AngularJs function in whole project structure in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I have an existing Project structure containing hundreds of folders and packages in Eclipse. I'm trying to search for an ng-click function in the whole structure using Ctrl+H and then in Javascript search. But it's failing to search for that function.
Any help on this please.

Comment: Search for the function in the controller bound to the view from where the function is being called.

Comment: @Tushar I'm not sure where the AngularJS controller file is kept and I want to search one ng-click function (Ex - loadData() ) quickly. How to search that?